# schema.xml for apache solr 6.4 version

Tags: xml

I have installed SOLR version 6.4.0 and am trying to figure out schema.xml file which I am not able to find to manually update the filelds.Is managed_schema.xml same as schema.xml and can I manually edit managed_schema.xml which is located under example\files\conf.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Solr now now uses Managed Schema by default. You can use a classic schema.xml file by changing the `<schemaFactory>` declaration in solrconfig.xml.

You can find detailed information on how to configure managed and classic schema in the Solr Reference Guide: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Schema+Factory+Definition+in+SolrConfig

Comment: Thanks for your reply.solrconfig.xml of Solr 6.4 doesn't have a ManagedIndexSchemaFactory definition.So just renaming the managed-schema file to schema.xml file will help ?

Comment: You have to explicitly declare the schemaFactory element in your solrconfig.xml with the class attribute "ClassicIndexSchemaFactory":

`<schemaFactory class="ClassicIndexSchemaFactory"/>`

Then you can use your schema.xml file.